# How to make one item order first in IQueryable

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

I have a linq to entities with a return of `IQueryable`. I need to make self join (`e.empid == empid`) to be first item. How can I do it?

```
public IQueryable<vmEmp> GetEmpUnder(string empid)
{
    var dataContext = new Entities();         
    var Emp = from e in dataContext.lstEmp.Where(e => e.Supervisor == empid || e.empid == empid)
                select new vmEmp
                {
                    EmpId = e.empid,
                    Name = e.LName + ", " + e.FName
                };

    var under = Emp.ToList().Where(e => DirectCount(e.EmpId) > 0);
    Emp = under.AsQueryable<vmEmp>();

    return Emp;
}
```

Comment: You need to either order the entire results with a custom comparison,  or do two queries and concatenate the results together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `orderby` with Booleans but note that it orders false before true, so you need to use `descending`. Also note you can combine that `Where` into the rest of the query:

```
var Emp = from e in dataContext.lstEmp
          where e.Supervisor == empid || e.empid == empid
          orderby e.empid == empid descending
          select new vmEmp
          {
              EmpId = e.empid,
              Name = e.LName + ", " + e.FName
          };
```

Or you can make two queries and concatenate them together, like this:

```
var Emp = 
    (from e in dataContext.lstEmp
     where e.Supervisor == empid
     select new vmEmp
     {
         EmpId = e.empid,
         Name = e.LName + ", " + e.FName
     }).Concat(
     from e in dataContext.lstEmp
     where e.empid == empid
     select new vmEmp
     {
         EmpId = e.empid,
         Name = e.LName + ", " + e.FName
     });
```

Comment: @jyparask In query syntax, the correct keywords are `where` and `orderby`, and they are case sensitive.

Comment: Sorry. My bad. I thought they would be like in methods.

Comment: @jyparask No problem. You may be thinking of [VB.NET's query syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763068.aspx) which uses a keywords that look a lot more like SQL